# Site's body and elements are stuck on 980px width, won't scale down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, sass

I'm trying to start the front end (only HTML/CSS) page on top of a Rails app and having trouble with the 320px viewport. There are elements that will not scale down, and I cannot figure out why.  I've gone through Inspect Element giving various elements a `max-width: 100%;` and/or `width: 100%;` along with other fixed widths, but something is wrong.

**index.html**

```
<div class="temple">
    <div class="container" style="height: 100%;"><div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="templeHeader">
            Every tourist sees the temples
        </div>
    </div></div> <!-- container and row -->
</div>
```

I have the container and row inside the "temple" because I want the image to be 100% width, not 100% minus the container's margins.

**layout.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@mixin center-both {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} 

.temple {
    /* background-image: image-url("temple.jpg"); */
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    .templeHeader {
        font-size: 52px;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        @include center-both;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that `.temple` and its children are 100% max width, so that `.templeHeader` centers properly in the 320px viewport?  I feel like I'm missing some initial setup that is messing this up.

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle with an image so we can better see what the problem is?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS**.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to add this into your HTML head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More here on [View port Control](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Currently with your HTML and this updated CSS below It is working fine for me, the .templeHeader is responsively centering.

> Please see bottom of code snippet for more.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@mixin center-both {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} 

* {
    margin:0; // It is a good idea to set these to zero at the start of
    padding:0; // your css and add them to each element individually as required
}

    .temple {
    /* background-image: image-url("temple.jpg"); */
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
}

    .templeHeader {  //fixed this block where the curly braces were not properly defined 
        font-size: 52px;
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        @include center-both;
}
```

> If you want the "Every tourist sees the temple" To not wrap onto multiple lines on smaller screens then use the following media query to change the font size at certain widths

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {

   .templeHeader 

        { font-size:8vw; } //this query will give you a nice responsive header all
                          // the way through various devices

}
```

Comment: Thank you!! You've alleviated so much head-scratching!

Answer (score -1):

You should remember to indent your html properly, it can get confusing if you don't.

Did you already try

```
.temple, .temple * {
    width: 100%; }
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with all that code with your explanation though, could you clarify? It seems to me you don't need all that.