# Css units (cm/px/pt) incorrect only on own site when changing view size

Tags: html, css, size

I'll use the following html as an example:

```
<div style="width:1cm; height:1cm; background-color:blue;">
</div>
```

When I render this html (chrome) and change the view size to samsung s8+ the square becomes tiny. However when i insert this html anywhere on most site (ex this very site), it still isn't exactly 1cm but it's at least a lot closer and it doesn't change size when changing the view size.

[image: my html]

[image: normal html]

Is there a HTML, css or js thing i'm missing the styling is identical.

Comment: I don't get that problem on my laptop using Edge WIndows10. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Check this link to understand https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/css-absolute-units/ Blew my mind too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing, the core issue was that (the width of) elements wasn't scaling past 980 px, causing items to shrink when the view width was less than 980. the solution is adding the following to the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

this is present on most websites explaining why the problem didn't occur on other sites

source: [Site's body and elements are stuck on 980px width, won't scale down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425506/sites-body-and-elements-are-stuck-on-980px-width-wont-scale-down)